When is the Probability Distribution equal to the Likelihood Function?
I was reading notes on Probability Distributions and noticed the following observation:

For a Univariate Normal Distribution, here is the Probability Distribution Function and the Likelihood Function:

$$
p(x | \mu, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
$$
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mu, \sigma^2 | x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} p(x_i | \mu, \sigma^2) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
$$

Here are the same formulas for a Multivariate Normal Distribution:

$$
p(\mathbf{x} | \mu, \Sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n |\Sigma|}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{x} - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \mu)\right)
$$
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mu, \Sigma | \mathbf{x}) = p(\mathbf{x} | \mu, \Sigma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n |\Sigma|}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{x} - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \mu)\right)
$$
I notice that in the case of the Univariate Distribution, there is a joint product sign $\prod_{i=1}^{n}$ in the Likelihood Function , but in the case of the Multivariate Distribution the joint product sign is not there.
Can someone please help me understand why this is? My guess is that since all the random variables in the multivariate case are jointly normal, there is no need for this? But I was hoping someone could walk me through the logic as to why there is no joint product sign in the multivariate likelihood.

You would have a product in the multivariate likelihood if your sample comprised multiple multivariate observations.  In the univariate case, you have an iid sample $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ of size $n$.  In the multivariate case, you have a single vector $\boldsymbol x$ whose components may exhibit correlation according to some covariance matrix $\Sigma$.  If instead you had iid multivariate vectors, say $(\boldsymbol x_1, \boldsymbol x_2, \ldots, \boldsymbol x_m)$, where each observation is a multivariate normal vector, then your likelihood will be proportional to the product of $m$ multivariate normal densities.
In short, the product notation corresponds to the sample size.  In the univariate case, you have a sample of size $n$.  In the multivariate case you wrote down, your sample has size $1$.  Do not confuse the dimension of the multivariate normal distribution with the sample size, because in a multivariate normal distribution, components may be correlated.

Thanks...I also wrote an answer below

I think I overcomplicated this.
We can write the formula for a $n$ dimensional multivariate normal in the following form (having removed matrix transposes):
$$
f(x_{k1}, x_{k2}, ..., x_{kN}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^N |\Sigma|}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} (x_{ki}-\mu_i) (\Sigma^{-1})_{ij} (x_{kj}-\mu_j)\right)
$$
Suppose we observe $m$ number of $n$ dimensional points:
$$ {\text Data (D): } \quad (X_1 = x_{11}, X_2 = x_{12}, ..., X_N = x_{1N}), (X_1 = x_{21}, X_2 = x_{22}, ..., X_N = x_{2N}), ..., (X_1 = x_{m1}, X_2 = x_{m2}, ..., X_N = x_{mN})$$
Then, the likelihood becomes:
$$
L(\mu, \Sigma | D) = \prod_{k=1}^{m} f(x_{k1}, x_{k2}, ..., x_{kN})
$$
So in fact, there is a joint product in the likelihood.
Here is an example. Suppose I have 5 points with 3 variables : $$D: (x_1, w_1, z_1), (x_2, w_2, z_2), (x_3, w_3, z_3), (x_4, w_4, z_4), (x_5, w_5, z_5)$$
The Normal Density for each individual point:
$$
f(X_1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^3 |\Sigma|}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} x_{1} - \mu_X \\ w_{1} - \mu_W \\ z_{1} - \mu_Z \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{X}^2 & \sigma_{XW} & \sigma_{XZ} \\ \sigma_{WX} & \sigma_{W}^2 & \sigma_{WZ} \\ \sigma_{ZX} & \sigma_{ZW} & \sigma_{Z}^2 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} x_{1} - \mu_X \\ w_{1} - \mu_W \\ z_{1} - \mu_Z \end{bmatrix}\right)
$$
$$
f(X_2) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^3 |\Sigma|}} \exp\left(-\frac{2}{2} \begin{bmatrix} x_{2} - \mu_X \\ w_{2} - \mu_W \\ z_{2} - \mu_Z \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{X}^2 & \sigma_{XW} & \sigma_{XZ} \\ \sigma_{WX} & \sigma_{W}^2 & \sigma_{WZ} \\ \sigma_{ZX} & \sigma_{ZW} & \sigma_{Z}^2 \end{bmatrix}^{-2} \begin{bmatrix} x_{2} - \mu_X \\ w_{2} - \mu_W \\ z_{2} - \mu_Z \end{bmatrix}\right)
$$
$$
f(X_3) = \frac{3}{\sqrt{(3\pi)^3 |\Sigma|}} \exp\left(-\frac{3}{3} \begin{bmatrix} x_{3} - \mu_X \\ w_{3} - \mu_W \\ z_{3} - \mu_Z \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{X}^3 & \sigma_{XW} & \sigma_{XZ} \\ \sigma_{WX} & \sigma_{W}^3 & \sigma_{WZ} \\ \sigma_{ZX} & \sigma_{ZW} & \sigma_{Z}^3 \end{bmatrix}^{-3} \begin{bmatrix} x_{3} - \mu_X \\ w_{3} - \mu_W \\ z_{3} - \mu_Z \end{bmatrix}\right)
$$
$$
f(X_4) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{(4\pi)^4 |\Sigma|}} \exp\left(-\frac{4}{4} \begin{bmatrix} x_{4} - \mu_X \\ w_{4} - \mu_W \\ z_{4} - \mu_Z \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{X}^4 & \sigma_{XW} & \sigma_{XZ} \\ \sigma_{WX} & \sigma_{W}^4 & \sigma_{WZ} \\ \sigma_{ZX} & \sigma_{ZW} & \sigma_{Z}^4 \end{bmatrix}^{-4} \begin{bmatrix} x_{4} - \mu_X \\ w_{4} - \mu_W \\ z_{4} - \mu_Z \end{bmatrix}\right)
$$
$$
f(X_5) = \frac{5}{\sqrt{(5\pi)^5 |\Sigma|}} \exp\left(-\frac{5}{5} \begin{bmatrix} x_{5} - \mu_X \\ w_{5} - \mu_W \\ z_{5} - \mu_Z \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{X}^5 & \sigma_{XW} & \sigma_{XZ} \\ \sigma_{WX} & \sigma_{W}^5 & \sigma_{WZ} \\ \sigma_{ZX} & \sigma_{ZW} & \sigma_{Z}^5 \end{bmatrix}^{-5} \begin{bmatrix} x_{5} - \mu_X \\ w_{5} - \mu_W \\ z_{5} - \mu_Z \end{bmatrix}\right)
$$
Now, the Likelihood becomes:
$$
L(\mu, \Sigma | D) = f(X_1) \cdot f(X_2) \cdot f(X_3) \cdot f(X_4) \cdot f(X_5)
$$
